# Table Flickering when add hover with related id=class in <tr>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a simple table with some content inside rows.
Since I want to display two types of content, I'm using in relative positioning on the `id="testClass" #testClassD+hover{...}`.

Every thing is fine but I've noticed that phase transition (moving a cursor downwards) generates in Flickering in the table. I'm trying to think what it could be  but i haven't found a good solution. Thanks in advance  for some advice.
ps: here the animated gif related at my problem : https://imgurs.com/a/v0cQ2DyD

```css
.textCenterRow {
    text-align: center;
}

#test5 {
    display: none;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* float: left; */
    /* margin-left: -156px; */
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}

tr:hover + #test5 {
    display:table-row;
    /* width: 200px */
}

tr:hover::after + #test5 {
    display:table-row;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; table-layout: fixed;" class="table  table-striped table-bordered table-hover white-background" >
  <tbody>               
   <tr id="test4">
      <td>B</td>
      <td class="textCenterRow"></td>
      <td class="textCenterRow"></td> 
      <td class="textCenterRow"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test5">
      <td>C</td>
      <td class="textCenterRow"></td>
      <td class="textCenterRow"></td> 
      <td class="textCenterRow"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I put my mouse on the B and moved slowly down - the <tr> showed up as expected, but I didn't see any flickering. This is Chrome. Have you been able to replicate in other browsers and/or machines?

Comment: ` <id="test4">` Why is this not a TR tag?

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane  an error of typing..sorry. now i've done the correction.

Comment: I think you need to make a snippet that matches the animated gif better.

Comment: Noticing in gif flickering only when going down.. May be try to remove display:none from #test5 in your css.. or the style with :after selector..